A conceptual problem related to the positivity of functional
I was going through this theorem in functional analysis after studying the bounded linear operators and continuity of the functionals :

Let $X$ denote a subspace of $B(T)$ with the sup norm, $1 \in X$ and $f$ be a linear functional on $X$. If $f$ is continuous and $\|f\|=f(1)$, then $f$ is positive.

I am writing the proof of exactly what is written in the text, I am following :
We have $|f(1)| \leq\|f\|\|1\|_{\infty}=\|f\|$.
Assume that $f$ is continuous and $\|f\|=f(1)$. To prove that $f$ is positive, it is enough to consider $x \in X$ such that $0 \leq x(t) \leq 1$ for all $t \in T$ and show that $f(x) \geq 0$. Let $y=2 x-1$, so that $-1 \leq y(t) \leq 1$ for all $t \in T$. First we show that $f(y)$ is a real number. If $\mathbf{K}=\mathbf{R}$, there is nothing to prove. Let $\mathbf{K}=\mathbf{C}$ and $f(y)=r+i s$, where $r$ and $s$ are real numbers. For every real number $a$, we have
$$|y+i a|^{2}=y^{2}+a^{2} \leq 1+a^{2}$$
so that
$$\begin{aligned}(s+a\|f\|)^{2} & =(s+a f(1))^{2} \leq|r+i(s+a f(1))|^{2} \\
& \leq|f(y+i a)|^{2} \leq\|f\|^{2}\left(1+a^{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Then $s^{2}+2 s a\|f\| \leq\|f\|^{2}$ for every real number $a$. Hence we conclude that $s=0$, that is, $f(y)=r \in \mathbf{R}$. As $\|y\|_{\infty} \leq 1$, we have $|r|=|f(y)| \leq \Vert f \Vert$. Thus
$$
f(x)=f\left(\frac{y+1}{2}\right)=\frac{r+\|f\|}{2} \geq 0
$$
Here are my questions:
(a) Why is this enough to "consider $x \in X$ such that $0 \leq x(t) \leq 1$ for all $t \in T$ and show that $f(x) \geq 0$. "?
(b) Whatever calculations are going to prove $f$ positive, what will be our backend thoughts? I mean, I want to know how step by step are they thinking to prove this thing.
Thank you, beforehand!!!
BTW, I should mention the definition of positive linear functional:
Let $X$ denote a linear space of scalar-valued function on a set $T$. A linear functional $f$ on $X$ is said to be positive if $f(x)\ge0$ whenever $x\in X$ and $x(t)\ge0$ for all $t\in T$.

If $x(t)$ is nonnegative and bounded $(x\neq 0),$ then $y(t)=|x|\infty^{-1}x(t)$ is nonnegative and $0\le y(t)\le 1.$ Next $f(x)=|x|\infty f(y).$ Concerning (b) it is easier to deal with $y=2x-1,$ as $|y|_\infty \le 1.$ Then we can make use of the norm of $f$ when $f$ is applied to $y.$

@RyszardSzwarc, I understood your points, and question (a) is solved. Thank you, for your help. But, for $\mathbf{K}=\mathbf{C}$ case, are those calculations coming naturally?
